# Convert Key file and Cer file to keystore

Tags: ssl, tomcat, openssl, keystore

My boss has used Openssl to buy a certificate and now I have this files:

- a key file, (yourdomain.key),
- a csr file (yourdomain.csr),
- a cer file (my_domain.cer) (IIS SSL Certificate (PKCS#7) received from comodo.com)

The file .cer has format

> -----BEGIN PKCS7-----
>
> .......
>
> -----END PKCS7-----

In order to config my SSL certificate on my tomcat, I want to regenerate a keystore file. I google it but no answer could help me. Can anyone help me to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Java *keytool* to create a keystore and import the certificates needed there

```
keytool -importcert -file my_domain.cer -keystore mykeystore.jks
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i got this error 
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate. 
Could you give me some idea to fix ?
The cer is the file I receive from comondo.com and has the format as I mention above.

Comment: I hear that the error can be caused by giving a wrong alias https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO1781 but I don't know in this case, my boss has created the key file by the command from here https://vn.godaddy.com/help/apache-generate-csr-certificate-signing-request-5269, no alias enterred.